# Unable to install IOS enterprise application

Tags: ios, enterprise, in-house-distribution

I have enterprise developer account . I want to distribute the app through URL . My app is hosted in AWS s3 bucket . The URL is alright and the apple developer certificate is also alright . When i try to access the url it showed me the install option . When i click install it it says "Unable to install appname . Please try again letter "

[image]

I have followed this Method:

[How to Distribute Enterprise iOS App in-house (without MDM)](https://medium.com/apps-studio/distributing-enterprise-ios-app-in-house-without-mdm-3ed015009893)

I have made the html file and put url like this .

```
<a href=”itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=url/appName.plist">
```

I have found the log . The log says

```
[IXSClientConnection remote_prioritizeCoordinatorForAppWithBundleID:completion:]: No coordinator found for com.bundle.dev and app is not vendable by App Store or is a hard error (1) so showing alert.
```

Please help .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution . I am posting so that it can help others .

When you generate the .ipa file you will get one .ipa file with project name and many other random named .ipa file in the same Apps folder . You have to upload all of them in AWS s3 bucket .

In my case i just uploaded the ProjectName.ipa file in S3 bucket .